# Can you use php to filter MySQL variables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm using $_GET variables to pull from a MySQL database to populate a dynamic page.  Some of the variables have special characters that must be filtered out to be used as a url. However, when pulling the variable from the url, the new string won't match the database variable due to the missing characters.  Is there a way to filter the variable from the database in the MySQL query before it tries to match it to the string?  Ex:

column_name = "ProductName™"
$GETvariable = "ProductName"

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE str_replace($array_of_characters, '', column_name) = '$GETvariable';
```

The above doesn't work, but is there something similar that will? Thanks.

Comment: You could use a regular expression or just 'like'.

Comment: I would use a like statement, but some products come up as Product™Name. The GET variable will be ProductName and not match.

Comment: a regular expression would work better. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it wrong way.

1. Best way to match an URL against database is to use an **unique ID** in the URL, just like Stack Overflow does:
    [stackoverflow.com/questions/15621389/curiosity-got-destroed-by-martians](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621389/curiosity-destroed-by-martians)
   despite of title changes it will **always** point to the right page
2. If you still want to use such unreliable source like slugified title to identify your pages, the **only** way is to **store the slugified version in database**